# Struts2 tiles How to set attribute values in dynamically…

Tags: struts2, tiles2, struts-config, struts-html

In tiles.xml set attribute values in static

`<tiles-definitions>`
  `<definition name="baseLayout" template="/site/layout.jsp" >`
      `<put-attribute name="body"   value="/index.jsp"/>`
      `<put-attribute name="top"   value="/site/footer.jsp"/>`
      `<put-attribute name="bottom"   value="/site/header.jsp"/>`
  `</definition>`
`</tiles-definitions>`

Can I give attribute values in dynamically.. .It is passable. Please give me some tips ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Preparer`. Here's [how](http://tiles.apache.org/tutorial/advanced/preparer.html).

Comment: tks doctrey. i successfully executed ViewPreparer. any other way execute pls let me know

Comment: You can use "expression" instead of "value" in the tiles.xml, take a look at http://symfony-world.blogspot.com/2013/02/dynamic-attribute-values-with-apache.html